# Return json array from client to spring controller

Tags: json, spring, return

I need to send data from the client html back to the spring controller.
I have a controller which generates a Json array whichh I sent via ajax to the html side when requested.
That functions well.
The Problem is I need to send the Json array back to another controller for evaluation and changes.
If I post the data and  assign an class object of the original class I get the error " Bad request" and it didn't work.
If I assign an object in the controller which consumes the post. That works
but I get an hashmap for which I dont know how to access.
I cant cast it to another class nor access it to work with it.
Since I am new to this can someone give me an advice how to consume the post 
on the receiving controller side.

Thanks

Khelvan.

Controller code ist stated below

controller 1 for  Get

```
    @RequestMapping("/Person")
    @ResponseBody
    public  ArrayList<Person> ajax_Person_array()
                  {
        ArrayList<Person> Dummy = new ArrayList<Person>();


        for ( x=0; x < 5; x++ ){

             Dummy.setName("Alfon");
                Dummy.setID("5");
                Dummy.setStree("Delta");
                Dummy.setName("Neutral");

                              Person.add(Dummy);
                     }


        return Dummy;
    }
```

Controller 2 for post

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajax", method=RequestMethod.POST,  consumes =  "application/json")
//public @ResponseBody String post( @RequestBody   Object  ajax_Person_array()) {    
    public @ResponseBody String post( @RequestBody      ArrayList<Person> ajax_Person_array()) {    
          System.out.println("First TEST");


           String Success =  "OK";

      return Success;
  }
```

Html : get ajax

```
                   var ajax_data;

        $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost:8080/Person",
              async: false,
              dataType:'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
            ajax_data = data;
            alert("success ");

            },
            error:function(){alert("something went wrong ");}
              });
    }
```

Html post ajax

$.ajax({ 
                url: "http://localhost:8080/ajax", 
                type: 'POST', 
                dataType: 'text',

```
           data: ajax_data,
           //  data: JSON.stringify(ajax_data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) { 
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function(data,status,er) { 
                alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
               document.write(data);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping (value="/ajax", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json") 
public @ResponseBody JSONObject post( @RequestBody JSONObject person) {

//Pass data to a service to process the JSON
}
```

For your ajax request, do not set dataType to 'Text'.  Set it to JSON

```
    $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:8080/ajax", 
       type: 'POST', 
       dataType: 'json',
       data: JSON.stringify(ajax_data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) { 
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function(data,status,er) { 
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
           document.write(data);
        }
    });
```